# Prevent android keyboard form causing lag

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, keyboard

I am attempting to use a swipe gesture to finish a fragment, and if the fragment is displaying the keyboard, the keyboard will be hidden. The following is a sample:

```
public void finishFragment() {
    View focus = getCurrentFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = null;
    if (focus != null) {
        imm = (InputMethodManager) focus.getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm.isActive()) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focus.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, since I am calling a service along side the fragment stack, the service is hanging up the UI display, thus giving it a laggy appearance. Does anyone know how I can hide the keyboard without calling a service or should I call an `Async` process? Even better, does anyone know how `onBackPressed()` removes the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 ways to control the keyboard on Android:

- Programmatically with the InputMethodManager like you are doing (which will as far as I know always requires you to call .getSystemService() to use)
- Using android:windowSoftInputMode="X" to specify the behavior of the keyboard in the context of the given activity tag in the AndroidManifest

So to answer your questions of: *"Does anyone know how I can hide the keyboard without calling a service"*? You could do the following in the AndroidManifest, where ActivityX is the activity you want to have this type of behavior.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.namespace.of.ActivityXYZ"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

This will serve to hide the keyboard initially for ActivityX, but I am not sure if this will give you the desired behavior/lack of laggyness when swiping to finish the fragment. Also try changing "stateHidden" to "stateAlwaysHidden" or "stateUnchanged". Checkout what these do [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) if you do not know.

Another approach would be: instead of checking the focus and getting the keyboard programmatically like you are doing, why not just finish() the activity managing the fragment you wish to end? This will also hide the keyboard if it was open.

Hope this helps!